# Can I edit queued MySQL binary logs for replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication

I have a simple Master-Slave replication set up, but Slave keeps falling behind do to what appears to be a simple checkout system. Master can keep up because it runs multi-threaded, but since the checkout is on a single table on a single database, the slave cannot multi-thread to catch up.

Consequently my binary logs are full of queries like:

```
UPDATE db.foo SET process_id = 123 WHERE id = 456 AND process_id IS NULL;
UPDATE db.foo SET process_id = 234 WHERE id = 567 AND process_id IS NULL;
```

I've analyzed the `general_log` (turned on slave temporarily) to estimate 9/10 queries are a regex of the above query.

1. Can I prevent these queries from being logged? How?
2. Can I scrub them from log before it's relayed to slave? How?
3. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

Can you avoid updating that *table* entirely?  If so, the Slave can be configured to have `replicate-ignore-table` on the Slave.  If it is an entire database (or could be moved to be such), then you can use the more efficient `binlog-ignore-db` on the Master.  Caveat -- If that table is needed on the Slave, well, it won't be there (or at least not up to date).

Plan B (close to what you are asking about):

```
SET SESSION sql_log_bin = 0;
UPDATE ...
SET SESSION sql_log_bin = 1;
```

Again, having the table inconsistent between Master and Slave leads to various Caveats.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-sql-log-bin.html